# How to limit the fiber modem bandwidth

Tags: windows-10, modem, telecommunication

I'm gonna install fiber in my home with an 100 Megabit connection.
I have 3 pc, I want to give to the first computer just 5 Megabit, the second computer 10 Megabit and the last one 85Megabit. 
How can I manage this thing?
The modem is an "Telecom Smart modem Technicolor".
All PCs have Windows 10.

Comment: Use a router with traffic shaping capabilities. Look at pfSense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no universal set of instructions for all routers, here is the general idea (Some googling should help):

1. Setup Static DHCP. This fixes the IP addresses of your computers.(somewhere in LAN settings under Advanced)
2. Go to QoS settings and and setup the priority. Also setup the minimum bandwidth of the 10Mbps and 85 Mbps computers.

Done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Cisco switch or router, you can add a policy on the interface to shape the traffic to the amount you wish. It is done pretty easily:

```
mls qos

ip access-list extended ACL_5mbps
 permit ip any any

class-map match-all CLASS_5mbps
  match access-group name ACL_5mbps

policy-map POLICY_5mbps
  class CLASS_5mbps
    police 5000000 100000 exceed-action drop

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description 5 Mbps limit port
 service-policy input POLICY_5mbps
```

It is even easier on a Cisco router:

```
mls qos

class-map match-any CLASS_5mbps
 match any 

policy-map POLICY_5mbps
 class CLASS_5mbps
  shape average 5000000

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 service-policy output POLICY_5mbps
```